# "expression is not assignable"

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

Im trying to find the second largest value of an array in order to create a equilibrium, the "largest_value" being the first and "large_value" being second, when i'm executing the it says "expression is not assignable"..
i just started learning.. Any help would be awesome.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<stdlib.h>
int main(){
int i=0,N=0,a;
int largest_value, large_value,temp,temp1;
int* array=NULL,b;
std::cout<<"Enter the Number of elements";
std::cin>>N;
array = new int[N];

//reading the elements.
for(i=0;i<N;i++){
    std::cin>>array[i];
}

//comparing elements.
largest_value=0;
for(i=0;i<N;i++){
    array[i]=temp;
    if(temp > largest_value)
        largest_value=temp;
        a = i;
}
large_value=0;

//picking the second best.
for(i=0;i<N;i++){
    (largest_value - array[i]) = large_value;
    if(temp < large_value)
        large_value = temp;
        b = i;
}       
std::cout<<"the Equlibrium is b/w" <<a << "and" <<b;
```

}

Comment: Sounds like you are looking for [std::nth_element](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/nth_element).

Comment: This doesn't address the question, but get in the habit of initializing objects with meaningful values rather than initializing them with default values and then overwriting them. In this case, that means changing `int* array = NULL; ... array = new int[N];` to `int* array = new int[N];`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
(largest_value - array[i]) = large_value;
```

assignments work the other way around
a=b assigns value of b to variable a